# How do I use group_concat and count each record in it?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am looking for a way to use the group_concat and count at the same time... Id like to have a result like this

Red, Red, Red, Red, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue

end up like this when finished

"Red(4),Blue(5)"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Use a subquery: `concat(field, count(*))`, and then `group_concat()` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(x.groups)
FROM
(
    SELECT
    CONCAT(color, '(', count(color), ')') AS groups
    FROM colors
    GROUP BY color   
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(color, '(', amount, ')') SEPARATOR ',') AS color_with_amount
FROM (  SELECT color, COUNT(*) AS amount
        FROM colors
        GROUP BY color) AS h
GROUP BY '1'
```